# How to validate XML against its XML Schema without local XSD file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com/first-schema.xsd"
  xmlns:f="http://example.com/second-schema.xsd">
  <f:foo>test</f:foo>
</root>
```

Now I want to validate whether this XML is XMLSchema-valid. I don't have these `first-schema.xsd` and `second-schema.xsd` files locally. Moreover, I don't know anything about them. I just want to make sure that my XML document is valid against **its** schemas. Is it possible to do in Java?

Comment: This makes no sense. If you don't have the schema file, then there's no way to determine if the document conforms to the schema.

Comment: @Mike it makes no sense of there is no way?

Comment: What is "**its** schemas"?  It isn't clear whether you want to validate against the `first-schema.xsd` and `second-schema.xsd` by retrieving from the URL used in the namespace URI, or whether you want to validate the instance document against another (unnamed) schema.  Please clarify what schema you want to validate the instance file against.

Comment: @Mads I want to validate `<f:foo>` element against `second-schema.xsd` and `<root>` against `first-schema.xsd`.

Comment: If the namespace-uri() uses a URL and the schemas are hosted at those URLs(convention, but not a requirement) then you could use the code suggested by @Blaise Doughan.  If you don't have a way to find/retrieve the schemas, it's hard to validate against them.

Comment: As Mike says above, this makes no sense. There is no central repository of schemas and it's not magic, so you do have to know about the location of the schemas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [javax.xml.validation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) APIs for this.

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
URL schemaURL = // The URL to your XML Schema; 
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaURL); 
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDOM);
validator.validate(source);
```

The example below demonstrates how to validate a JAXB object model against a schema, but you'll see it's easy to replace the JAXBSource with a DOMSource for DOM:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I explained in the question that I **don't have URL** to my XML Schema, since I don't know what XML Schema is used in the document.

Comment: You could use a StAX XMLStreamReader to parse the XML.  Then you could snoop the schemas from the xmlns declarations (Note the URIs in xmlns declarations are not guaranteed to be real URLs).  Then use the validate code with a StAXSource instead.